# How to move to second layout in android after fingerprint authentication successful

Tags: java, android, mobile, layout, fingerprint

I have made the first layout in android as fingerprint authentication and it has successfully authenticate my fingerprint but how to make it move from the fingerprint layout directly to the second layout...

Please anyone help me.......

This is the coding of FingerprintAuthenticationActivity.java :

```
public class FingerprintAuthenticationActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

private static final String KEY_NAME = "example_key";
private FingerprintManager fingerprintManager;
private KeyguardManager keyguardManager;
private KeyStore keyStore;
private KeyGenerator keyGenerator;
private Cipher cipher;
private FingerprintManager.CryptoObject cryptoObject;
private FingerprintHandler fingerprintHandler;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_fingerprint_authentication);

    keyguardManager = (KeyguardManager) getSystemService(KEYGUARD_SERVICE);
    fingerprintManager = (FingerprintManager) getSystemService(FINGERPRINT_SERVICE);

    if (!keyguardManager.isKeyguardSecure()) {

        Toast.makeText(this, "Lock screen security not enabled in Settings",
                Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        return;
    }

    if (ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(this,
            Manifest.permission.USE_FINGERPRINT) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
        Toast.makeText(this, "Fingerprint authentication permission not enabled",
                Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

        return;
    }

    if (!fingerprintManager.hasEnrolledFingerprints()) {

        // This happens when no fingerprints are registered.
        Toast.makeText(this, "Register at least one fingerprint in Settings",
                Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        return;
    }

    generateKey();

    if (cipherInit()) {
        cryptoObject = new FingerprintManager.CryptoObject(cipher);
        FingerprintHandler helper = new FingerprintHandler(this);
        helper.startAuth(fingerprintManager,cryptoObject);
    }

}

protected void generateKey() {
    try {
        keyStore = KeyStore.getInstance("AndroidKeyStore");
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    try {
        keyGenerator = KeyGenerator.getInstance(KeyProperties.KEY_ALGORITHM_AES,
                "AndroidKeyStore");
    } catch (NoSuchAlgorithmException | NoSuchProviderException e) {
        throw new RuntimeException("Failed to get KeyGenerator instance", e);
    }

    try {
        keyStore.load(null);
        keyGenerator.init(new KeyGenParameterSpec.Builder(KEY_NAME, KeyProperties.PURPOSE_ENCRYPT | KeyProperties.PURPOSE_DECRYPT)
                .setBlockModes(KeyProperties.BLOCK_MODE_CBC)
                .setUserAuthenticationRequired(true)
                .setEncryptionPaddings(KeyProperties.ENCRYPTION_PADDING_PKCS7)
                .build());
        keyGenerator.generateKey();
    } catch (NoSuchAlgorithmException | InvalidAlgorithmParameterException | CertificateException | IOException e) {
        throw new RuntimeException(e);
    }

}

public boolean cipherInit() {
    try {
        cipher = Cipher.getInstance(KeyProperties.KEY_ALGORITHM_AES + "/" + KeyProperties.BLOCK_MODE_CBC + "/"
                        + KeyProperties.ENCRYPTION_PADDING_PKCS7);
    } catch (NoSuchAlgorithmException | NoSuchPaddingException e) {
        throw new RuntimeException("Failed to get Cipher", e);
    }

    try {
        keyStore.load(null);
        SecretKey key = (SecretKey) keyStore.getKey(KEY_NAME,null);
        cipher.init(Cipher.ENCRYPT_MODE, key);
        return true;
    } catch (KeyPermanentlyInvalidatedException e) {
        return false;
    } catch (KeyStoreException | CertificateException | UnrecoverableKeyException | IOException
            | NoSuchAlgorithmException | InvalidKeyException e) {
        throw new RuntimeException("Failed to init Cipher", e);
    }
}
}
```

This is FingerprintHandler.java :

```
public class FingerprintHandler extends FingerprintManager.AuthenticationCallback {

private CancellationSignal cancellationSignal;
private Context appContext;


public FingerprintHandler(Context context) {
    appContext = context;}


public void startAuth(FingerprintManager manager, FingerprintManager.CryptoObject cryptoObject) {

    cancellationSignal = new CancellationSignal();

    if (ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(appContext, Manifest.permission.USE_FINGERPRINT) !=
            PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
        return;
    }
    manager.authenticate(cryptoObject, cancellationSignal, 0, this, null);
}

@Override
public void onAuthenticationError(int errMsgId,
                                  CharSequence errString) {
    Toast.makeText(appContext,
            "Authentication error\n" + errString,
            Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
}

@Override
public void onAuthenticationHelp(int helpMsgId,
                                 CharSequence helpString) {
    Toast.makeText(appContext,
            "Authentication help\n" + helpString,
            Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
}

@Override
public void onAuthenticationFailed() {
    Toast.makeText(appContext,
            "Authentication failed.",
            Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
}

@Override
public void onAuthenticationSucceeded(
        FingerprintManager.AuthenticationResult result) {

    Toast.makeText(appContext,
            "Authentication succeeded.",
            Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();


}

}
```

This is the second layout that I need to move after fingerprint success EmployeeLoginActivity.java :

```
public class EmployeeLoginActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_employee_login);

    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Something like this should work to start the new `Activity` on a successful authentication:

```
@Override
public void onAuthenticationSucceeded(
        FingerprintManager.AuthenticationResult result) {

    Toast.makeText(appContext,
            "Authentication succeeded.",
            Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

    appContext.startActivity(new Intent(appContext,
        EmployeeLoginActivity.class));
}
```